# Windows installer does not fail when custom action returns an error

Tags: error-handling, windows-installer, custom-action

I am trying to modify a custom action of type `3137` and a `.dll` source (with say a target `DWORD InstallFunction( MSIHANDLE hInstall )`) to return some error codes in certain situation and I am expecting that window installer fails and prompt me with an error message or something.

However, when I do return an `ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT` code (or any error code in that matter) from the module that has been called, the installer completely ignores the returned value and proceeds to complete the installation as if nothing has happened.

How do I get the installer to fail as well? I am new to the whole windows installer API/concept so I would truly appreciate any advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom action has the msidbCustomActionTypeContinue flag set. Thus the installer ignores the return code. Removing this flag will solve the problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368071(v=VS.85).aspx